# Dark colours are blocky when displaying non "flat" images

Tags: display, colors

My new display has a very odd fault. When scenes with a lot of color (gradients etc.) are on screen the blacks and darker colors become strangely pixelated (picture below.)

[A Photograph of the display showcasing the fault at the edges of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUC3n.png)

Interestingly the problem does not occur when the system is displaying "flat" images like menus and retro games that use block colors instead of photos and gradients.

Any thoughts much appreciated!